# If the user is using their mouse left-handed, are .leftMouseDown and .rightMouseDown swapped?

Tags: mouse, hid, human-interface

I want to know that the system handles this for me. I really hope it does.

If the user is left-handed, and so the left and right mouse buttons' meanings are swapped, then do all `NSEvent` things related to these two buttons also swap?

For an in-code example, I want to know if this is left-handed-user-friendly:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown(with: event)
    performPrimaryEvent()
}


override func rightMouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.rightMouseDown(with: event)
    performSecondaryEvent()
}
```

[The official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nseventmask/nseventmaskleftmousedown) says nothing and [Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q="nseventmaskleftmousedown"+left-handed) are futile...

Answer (score 1):

I plugged in a mouse just to test this. It turns out the answer is yes! All these values and callbacks are automatically flipped.